# How to use an expression in function from other function in julia

Tags: function, julia, expression, metaprogramming

When I try those code below:

```
function f(x)
    Meta.parse("x -> x " * x) |> eval
end

function g(x)
    findall(Base.invokelatest(f,x),[1,2,3]) |> println
end

g("<3")
```

Julia throws "The applicable method may be too new" error.

If I tried these code below:

```
function f(x)
    Meta.parse("x -> x " * x) |> eval
end

findall(f("<3"),[1,2,3]) |> println
```

Julia could give me corrected result: [1, 2]

How can I modify the first codes to use an String to generate function in other function, Thx!

Test in Julia 1.6.7

Comment: Instead evaling strings (which is frowned upon), you can pass anonymous functions instead: `findall(<(3), [1,2,3])`. This is a better approach in general.

Comment: Fully agreed. However, for some reason recently many users on SO ask about parsing strings in Julia (as @DNF noted - this should be done normally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
function g(x)
    h = f(x)
    findall(x -> Base.invokelatest(h, x) ,[1,2,3]) |> println
end

g("<3")
```

The difference in your code is that when you write:

```
Base.invokelatest(f, x)
```

you invoke `f`, but `f` is not redefined. What you want to do is `invokelatest` the function that is returned by `f` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me understand the 'Base.invokelatest'

Comment: There's another point confused me. In my f(x), I parsed "x -> x". Why I have to add "x ->" befor "Base.invokelatest..." ?

Comment: Because `findall` takes a predicate as a first argument. In my solution I pass an anonymous function that can be compiled (i.e. is not dynamically defined) to `findall`. The dynamically defined function is only invoked in its body. This way compiler has a known function to dispatch to in `findall`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a macro instead of function:

```
macro f(expr)
    Meta.parse("x -> x " * expr)
end
```

Now you can just do:

```
julia> filter(@f("<3"), [1,2,3])
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
```